# How to configure Appium test suite on Jenkins to run everyday and start Appium Server and Emulator programmatically

Tags: android, maven, jenkins, testng, appium

I tried to find answers for it but couldn't find in Stack overflow. what I want is to run my mobile test suite which I have written for an android app in Jenkins. I want to start Appium server and emulator programmatically and just provide maven command to execute the build.

it is a maven project and I am using Testng framework, so basically, I want to start appium server beforesuite or beforeclass execution. please let me know if anyone has done that, I tried many ways to do that but nothing worked.